# The Python service is crashing in PyCharm in debug mode with an error : Process finished with exit code 138 (interrupted by signal 10: SIGBUS)

Tags: python, pycharm, macos-monterey

The Python service is crashing in PyCharm in debug mode with an error:

> Process finished with exit code 138 (interrupted by signal 10: SIGBUS)

- IDE: PyCharm 2022.1.3 (Community Edition)
- OS:macOS Monterey (Version 12.4)

Is there any fix to address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

[This helped me](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-43101/Exit-Code-138-With-PyCharm-Debugger)

It mentions to set these two environment variables in your run configuration:

```
PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=NO
PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL=NO
```

Didn't had the issue since then.